# XML unmarshal dynamic response with indices in field names

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I am attempting to unmarshal a "dynamic" XML response, but I am not sure how to approach it. A server responds with a pretty large response, so I would prefer not parsing the response twice. The XML looks like this:

```
...
<nic_cnt>2</nic_cnt>
<ifindex1>eno1</ifindex1>
<ifindex2>eno2</ifindex2>
...
```

So the `nic_cnt` field defines how may times `ifindex` will occur. Since I do not know how many times `ifindex` will occur, I cannot statically define the struct fields needed to unmarshal the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a slice with the `,any` XML tag option to tell the [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) package to put any XML tag into it. This is documented at [`xml.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal):

> ```
> If the XML element contains a sub-element that hasn't matched any
>    of the above rules and the struct has a field with tag ",any",
>    unmarshal maps the sub-element to that struct field.
> ```

For the `<ifindexXX>` tags use another struct which contains an `XMLName` field of type [`xml.Name`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Name) so the actual field name will be available if you need to filter only fields that start with `ifindex`.

Let's parse the following XML:

```
<root>
    <nic_cnt>2</nic_cnt>
    <ifindex1>eno1</ifindex1>
    <ifindex2>eno2</ifindex2>
</root>
```

We can model it with:

```
type Root struct {
    NicCnt  int     `xml:"nic_cnt"`
    Entries []Entry `xml:",any"`
}

type Entry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Value   string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

Example code parsing it:

```
var root Root
if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &root); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v", root)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/noS5n6PgSig)):

```
{NicCnt:2 Entries:[
    {XMLName:{Space: Local:ifindex1} Value:eno1}
    {XMLName:{Space: Local:ifindex2} Value:eno2}]}
```

Note that `Root.Entries` will also contain other unmapped XML tags. If you only care about tags that start with `ifindex`, this is how you can "filter" them:

```
for _, e := range root.Entries {
    if strings.HasPrefix(e.XMLName.Local, "ifindex") {
        fmt.Println(e.XMLName.Local, ":", e.Value)
    }
}
```

If the XML also contains an additional tag:

```
<other>something else</other>
```

Output will be (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BNrIiiXl8_R)):

```
{NicCnt:2 Entries:[
    {XMLName:{Space: Local:ifindex1} Value:eno1}
    {XMLName:{Space: Local:ifindex2} Value:eno2}
    {XMLName:{Space: Local:other} Value:something else}]}
ifindex1 : eno1
ifindex2 : eno2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Just so that I'm sure I understand: any XML field not explicitly defined in the struct, will be unmarshaled to `Entries` slice due to the `any` tag option?

Comment: @rhillhouse Yes, but as my last example shows, the tag name is available and you can simply filter out those you don't need.

Comment: But How can I use it or define a struct on my protobuf?, current I can not import `xml.Name` in my protobuf.